# How do I check if Outlook has new mail using the Microsoft.Office.Interop assemblies?

Tags: .net, ms-office, office-interop

I simply want to be able to check, while outlook is open, if it has new mail from a Windows forms application.

I'm able to capture the NewMail event(ApplicationEvents_11_NewMailEventHandler), but if new mail notification was already active before my code runs, it is not fired.

Also, how can I do this without Outlook popping up the warning windows about third party application access? In other words, how do I tell outlook to trust me? (That part may better suited to superuser)